# Adding Nodes to an AnchorPane (inside Scroll Pane), Javafx

Tags: javafx, java-8, scrollpane

I can add elements to an `AnchorPane` that is inside a `ScrollPane`. However they come in temporarily hidden. The second I click on the `AnchorPane`, the elements show up. I tried to do thing like `element.toFront()`, but with no success. Any ideas how to get elements to show up right away?

Sample code would like:

```
AnchorPane host= new AnchorPae();

ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(host);
AnchorPane node = new AnchorPane();

host.getChildren().add(node);
```

I tried things like requestFocus() on each of these nodes, but without success. I also tried to mimic a mouse click event but it did not work. everything shows once I physically click on the AnchorPane.

Comment: Post sample code with testable case where "they come in temporarily hidden. The second I click on the AnchorPane, the elements show up". Also you are using JavaFX 8, specify it in question tags.

Comment: The code is not that much decoupled yet. I will have to do a lot of factoring to get a testable chunk out of it. I thought just in case someone came across this issue. I will post back once I refactor the code. thanks :)